# MS Edge and IE don't redirect after login and get HTTP 302 code

Tags: php, internet-explorer, nginx, microsoft-edge, http-status-code-302

OS: FreeBSD 11-RELEASE (the same problem on 10.3-RELEASE)

Engine: nginx-1.10.1_2,2

App language: php70-7.0.12

CMS: Symfony 1.4

---

0) I use MS Edge or MS IE11.

1) I go to www.my.web .

2) Then I click to login and I'm on www.my.web/index.php/login .

3) I enter credentials and all browsers parse HTTP properly excepting Edge and IE11.

4) Edge and IE11 report "Cannot connect with website".

Look at the server log access.

Edge:

```
"POST /index.php/login HTTP/1.1" 302 113 "http://www.my.web/index.php/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393"
```

Firefox:

```
"POST /index.php/login HTTP/1.1" 302 113 "http://www.my.web/index.php/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 21265 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
```

Chrome:

```
"POST /index.php/login HTTP/1.1" 302 113 "http://www.my.web/index.php/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36"
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 21262 "http://www.my.web/index.php/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36"
```

Opera:

```
"POST /index.php/login HTTP/1.1" 302 113 "http://www.my.web/index.php/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36 OPR/40.0.2308.90"
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 21273 "http://www.my.web/index.php/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36 OPR/40.0.2308.90"
```

Safari:

```
"POST /index.php/login HTTP/1.1" 302 113 "http://www.my.web/index.php/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2"
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 21281 "http://www.my.web/index.php/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2"
```

Redirection code below:

```
/**
* Redirects the request to another URL.
*
* @param string $url        An associative array of URL parameters or an internal URI as a string
* @param int    $delay      A delay in seconds before redirecting. This is only needed on
*                           browsers that do not support HTTP headers
* @param int    $statusCode The status code
*
* @throws InvalidArgumentException If the url argument is null or an empty string
*/

public function redirect($url, $delay = 0, $statusCode = 302)
{
if (empty($url))
{
  throw new InvalidArgumentException('Cannot redirect to an empty URL.');
}

$url = $this->genUrl($url, true);
// see #8083
$url = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $url);

if (sfConfig::get('sf_logging_enabled'))
{
  $this->dispatcher->notify(new sfEvent($this, 'application.log', array(sprintf('Redirect to "%s"', $url))));
}

// redirect
$response = $this->context->getResponse();
$response->clearHttpHeaders();
$response->setStatusCode($statusCode);

// The Location header should only be used for status codes 201 and 3..
// For other code, only the refresh meta tag is used
if ($statusCode == 201 || ($statusCode >= 300 && $statusCode < 400))
{
  $response->setHttpHeader('Location', $url);
}

$response->setContent(sprintf('<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="%d;url=%s"/></head></html>', $delay, htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_QUOTES, sfConfig::get('sf_charset'))));
$response->send();
}
```

Please look at the captured data.
For both cases server responded with url refresh.
But Edge does not parse it and "Hmm, we can't reach this page."

Edge request:
`,4EjM@z. aPX   PPOST /index.php/login HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
Referer: http://www.my.web/index.php/login
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: www.my.web
Content-Length: 198
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

Server reply:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 24 Oct 2016 19:45:20 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=300
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.12
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache

DATA reply:
html head meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.my.web/"/>/head /html

Chrome request:
`,4E-pE@z. PN50PJPOST /index.php/login HTTP/1.1
Host: www.my.web
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 198
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://www.my.web
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://www.my.web/index.php/login
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Server reply:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 24 Oct 2016 19:03:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=300
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.12
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache

DATA reply:
html head meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.my.web/"/> /head /html>

---

Old server reply for all browsers:
Location: http://my.web/

New server reply for all browsers:
: http: //my.web/

I think above generates problem and Edge&IE cannot handle it.

Comment: We need to see your code.

Comment: I have the same website on Apache with PHP5 and Edge and IE work ok. But the website where is the problem is over VPN and IP address to this site is local. Does it make the problem?

Comment: I've switched this server to world and no success. So the VPN is not a problem.

Comment: My workaround is add HTTP header adding.
location ~ \.php($|/)
{ ...;
add_header      Location        $script always;
...; }

But the another problem ocurred. For tis reason when I accet some actions on my page like Save or Search, website goes to home page of the site. But actions is done of course. So I have a question. Is this a bug on nginx or PHP to send wrong location in HTTP header starting from char : as I described above?